# in EmEditor, a space width is not equal to a English letter width , how to resolve it?

Tags: width, space, emeditor

see the picture, the width of space is only equal to half of width of "a", how to make them equal , thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select a non-proportional (fixed-width) font. Select **Font** on the **View** menu, click the **Change** button, and select a non-proportional font such as `Consolas`.